# Nodejs fs.writefile throwing TypeError: First argument must be a string

Tags: node.js, string, base64, fs

Code aiming to save base64 into a specified filepath

```
class FileURI {
  constructor() {
    this.id = shortid.generate();
    this.localURI = 'public/uploads/' + this.id + '.jpg';
    this.localURIexplicit = './' + this.localURI;  //Required by XXXX
    this.publicURL = 'https://xxx.xyz/' + this.localURI;
  }

  static saveB64toUrl(b64data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let fileLoc = new FileURI();
      fs.writeFile(fileLoc.localURI, new Buffer(b64data, 'base64'),
        function (err) {
          if (err) reject(err);
          else {
            console.log("filename created: " + fileLoc.localURI + " in " + fileLoc.publicURL);
            resolve(fileLoc);
          }
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Even after carefully checking [fs doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) and performing the obvious approaches of manually changing the file path to the simplest `fs.writeFile('public/uploads/a.jpg', new Buffer(b64data, 'base64')`, I still **always** get the following error.

> `0|server   | TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.`

It was propperly working before, and even by thoroughly checking line by line I can't find out which change it's been made so far.

I really hope is just a typo or misunderstanding in the required URI format.

Comment: It is most likely `new Buffer(b64data, 'base64')` that's throwing - not `writeFile` - so `b64data` is what you should be looking at.

Comment: So, even though I was really stucked, @cartant tip let me check in the right place. FYI a really small change in the way to interact with *b64data*  was the reason.
However I'd like to understand why the actual error was "First argument" rather than missing writeFile or so...